# C# MVC Razor or Master/Content performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm starting a new project with MVC and I've never used the Razor engine.  Will there be any performance gains or hits as compared to using the standard Content/Master pages?  I know that Razor looks better and seems easier to program for, but what is the cost?

Thanks

Comment: There is no cost. Razor is just-in-time compiled, just as normal content/master pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor, according to these tests, is slightly slower:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828961/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-performance)

Comment: I must be reading these results incorrectly because to me it appears to be slower (although I don't think these tests are enough to make a meaningful conclusion on a full scale application)

Comment: Oh wow!  Thanks :)  Ok, I just checked it out, the results are confusing and they are for the Betas and RCs.  Is there any data with the final version?

Comment: @Marek Karbarz - Thanks, I am slow sometimes.

Comment: The final conclusion, when the tester turned off Debug in web.config, was that they were essentially equal.