# measuring performance ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax  vs. Classic ASP 

Tags: asp-classic, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

Any info on classic ASP in comparison to [ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages)?

- Which can handle more traffic and which is faster?
- Are there any benchmarking tests between the two?

I found this question: [ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828961/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-performance), but it's only about Razor.

Comment: What does *`Razor (without Controllers)`* mean?

Comment: There is no MVC without controllers - that's the C in MVC.  Please clarify exactly what you are looking for. Even if Classic ASP appears to be more performant (which I doubt), there are many reasons not to use it.

Comment: I understand you can do Razor without controllers, hence this question.

Comment: Classic ASP is not an appropriate choice for modern software development. As such, it's meaningless to compare it to Razor. Voted to close as "not constructive".

Comment: Why close, at least a classic asp benchmark would be helpful to compare the two..

Comment: ASP.NET Web Pages is compiled and managed code. Classic ASP is interpreted script. Compiled code executes faster than script-based languages. Not sure why this question was closed - it deserves an answer.

Comment: There is an important point, which I think we all need to be aware that due to a bug, razor always compile into debug mode. So it will slow in comparision with WebForm view. See http://forums.asp.net/t/1625220.aspx/1. However, I agree with Mike that why this question is closed. I think we need to encourage users to ask these kind questions instead of discouraging them by quickly closing the question.

Comment: I agree that this question should not have been closed.  It seems like a valid question that Classic ASP developers may have (there are still those around).  Those looking to possibly move to asp.net webpages may find this useful since the way webpages sites are made is similar to how it's done with classicASP.

Comment: There are 3 ASP.NET technologies which are WebForm, MVC and Web Pages.  The Web Pages is just like MVC technologies but lacking MVC.